# Could not delete/rename/re-add an SSH key from GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I have created an SSH key in GitLab.

Unfortunately, when I pasted my SSH public key it renamed the title of My SSH key with my email. My main intention was to rename the Title.

As it is not supported (as per I explored), I was trying to delete the SSH key. But unfortunately, this feature is not working. I have tested from SSH key list *(link: https://gitlab.com/profile/keys )* and individual SSH key *(link: [https://gitlab.com/profile/keys/{key-id}](https://gitlab.com/profile/keys/%7Bkey-id%7D) )* page. In both cases, it asked for a prompt for confirmation of deletion but actually does not work.

Is there any other way to rename or (delete + add) or re-add an SSH key in GitLab?